# Javascript/CSS token field. Much like Cocoa's one

Tags: javascript, jquery, cocoa, web-applications

I've made a desktop application which uses Cocoa's NSTokenField:

> [alt text http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Art/tokenfield.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Art/tokenfield.jpg)
>
> More info about it here: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Now I'm remaking this application as webapplication using PHP and AJAX. Is there a way to use a token field (comma seperated) in a web page, so the user can enter e-mail addresses and they are automatically styled like this? A jQuery plug in would be great. Otherwise just normal JavaScript. I thought of a way in CSS which gives every word a style, but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this plugin:

- [jQuery Token Input](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)  ([demos](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html))

[image: img]